# Pasted tables from Jupyter to StackOverflow get ill-formatted

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Consider the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name":["john","jim","eric","jim","john","jim","jim","eric","eric","john"],
    "category":["a","b","c","b","a","b","c","c","a","c"],
    "amount":[100,200,13,23,40,2,43,92,83,1]
})
df
```

When I copy the output, I get a not nicely formatted table here on StackOverflow:

```
name    category    amount  sum count
0   john    a   100 140 2
1   jim b   200 225 3
2   eric    c   13  105 2
3   jim b   23  225 3
4   john    a   40  140 2
5   jim b   2   225 3
6   jim c   43  43  1
7   eric    c   92  105 2
8   eric    a   83  83  1
9   john    c   1   1   1
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from an `ipython` terminal session I can paste:

```
In [73]: df
Out[73]: 
   name category  amount
0  john        a     100
1   jim        b     200
2  eric        c      13
3   jim        b      23
4  john        a      40
5   jim        b       2
6   jim        c      43
7  eric        c      92
8  eric        a      83
9  john        c       1
```

From a notebook, it looks like `print(df)` gives a better result:

```
   name category  amount
0  john        a     100
1   jim        b     200
2  eric        c      13
3   jim        b      23
4  john        a      40
5   jim        b       2
6   jim        c      43
7  eric        c      92
8  eric        a      83
9  john        c       1
```

The copy selection should be a solid color block.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @hpaulj! Your `print` suggestion solves the problem!